# Stop script from creating PDF duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation, delete-file

I'm new to the coding thing but I've been able to write a script that will take info from a spreadsheet and turn it into a PDF. The trouble I'm having now is trying to find a way to get the code to stop before creating duplicates every time I run the code.  I've tried a try catch block, return, throw and if else statements but I'm just not getting it.  I have spent a lot of time searching to see if I could find a solution but can't seem to figure it out.

```
function createBulkPDFs(){
  
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(//myfileID);
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(//myfolderID);
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(//myfolderID);
  const RemittanceInfo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Query");
   const data = RemittanceInfo.getRange(2,1,RemittanceInfo.getLastRow()-1,13).getDisplayValues();
  const checkedColumnIndex = 12;
  const addCheckbox = RemittanceInfo.getRange(2,13,RemittanceInfo.getLastRow()-1,1).insertCheckboxes();
  const check = "TRUE";
  let Print = [];
  
   data.forEach(function(row) {
     if (row[checkedColumnIndex] = check) {
         return;
         }
     else if (row[checkedColumnIndex] !== check){
       return addCheckbox
     }
    else  (row[checkedColumnIndex] !== check){
      return createPDF(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[9],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[11],row[0]+" "+row[9]+" Inv "+row[6],docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder);
    }
    Print.push([check]);
  });
  RemittanceInfo.getRange(2,13,RemittanceInfo.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(Print);  
}

function createPDF(Vendor,Street,City,Prov,PostalCode,DatePaid,Account,Invoice,AmountDue,Chq,Memo,pdfName,docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder) {
 
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{Vendor}", Vendor);
  body.replaceText("{Street}", Street);
  body.replaceText("{City}", City);
  body.replaceText("{Prov}", Prov);
  body.replaceText("{PostalCode}", PostalCode);
  body.replaceText("{DatePaid}", DatePaid);
  body.replaceText("{Account}", Account);
  body.replaceText("{Invoice}", Invoice);
  body.replaceText("{AmountDue}", AmountDue);
  body.replaceText("{Chq}", Chq);
  body.replaceText("{Memo}", Memo);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  const PDFContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  pdfFolder.createFile(PDFContentBlob).setName(pdfName);
  tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);
}
```

I'd really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: So it's creating duplicates *only* because you ran the script again? Have you considered creating the PDF only if `row[13] != "✔"`?

Comment: Correct, the script pulls data from a query that is always adding new data so it needs to be able to run multiple times and only create new PDFs, not ones that have been previously generated.  Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sleeping on this for a few days, I was able to figure out my issue.  The code below works for creating a single copy of a PDF and only generates one copy.  Thank you for all your help Diego!

````
  
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(" template ID ");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(" temp folder ID ");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(" PDF fold ID ");
  const RemittanceInfo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Query");
  const data = RemittanceInfo.getRange(2,1,RemittanceInfo.getLastRow()-1,13).getDisplayValues();
  const addCheckbox = RemittanceInfo.getRange(2,13,RemittanceInfo.getLastRow()-1,1).insertCheckboxes();
  const checkedColumnIndex = 13;
  const check = "TRUE";
  let Print = [];
  
   data.forEach(function(row) {
     if(row[checkedColumnIndex-1] !== check) {
       createPDF(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[9],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[11],row[0]+" "+row[9]+" Inv "+row[6],docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder);
    }
    Print.push([check]);
  });
  RemittanceInfo.getRange(2,checkedColumnIndex,RemittanceInfo.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(Print);
}

function createPDF(Vendor,Street,City,Prov,PostalCode,DatePaid,Account,Invoice,AmountDue,Chq,Memo,pdfName,docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder) {
 
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{Vendor}", Vendor);
  body.replaceText("{Street}", Street);
  body.replaceText("{City}", City);
  body.replaceText("{Prov}", Prov);
  body.replaceText("{PostalCode}", PostalCode);
  body.replaceText("{DatePaid}", DatePaid);
  body.replaceText("{Account}", Account);
  body.replaceText("{Invoice}", Invoice);
  body.replaceText("{AmountDue}", AmountDue);
  body.replaceText("{Chq}", Chq);
  body.replaceText("{Memo}", Memo);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  const PDFContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  pdfFolder.createFile(PDFContentBlob).setName(pdfName);
  tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

This is duplicating the PDF because you already ran the script, so there isn't actually any error and thus the [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) won't do what you expect it to do.

Since you're checking the box in Column N to indicate that a PDF was created, simply look to see if that box is already checked when running the script. If not checked, then create the PDF.

```
function createBulkPDFs(){
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(//myfileID);
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(//myfolderID);
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(//myfolderID);
  const RemittanceInfo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Query");
  const data = RemittanceInfo.getRange(2,1,RemittanceInfo.getLastRow()-1,14).getDisplayValues();
  const checkedColumnIndex = 13;
  const check = "TRUE";
  
  let Print = [];
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    if (row[checkedColumnIndex] !== check) {
      createPDF(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[9],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[11],row[0]+" Inv "+row[6]+" - "+row[9],docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder);
    }
    Print.push([check]);
  });
  
  RemittanceInfo.getRange(2,checkedColumnIndex+1,RemittanceInfo.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(Print);  
}
```

Notes:

- Defined `checkedColumnIndex` & `check` so they're easier to change later.
- Because you're using [getDisplayValues(),](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) the values returned by checkboxes are either the strings "TRUE" or "FALSE" (case-sensitive). Thankfully, the string "TRUE" will be correctly interpreted into a checkbox–no need to pass a boolean.
- Not using an arrow function simply because it messes up the formatting in the Apps Script editor.
- Pushing a value to `Print` even if skipping the PDF creation because otherwise the checks won't correspond with the correct row.
- When printing back to the sheet, remember to offset `checkedColumnIndex` since arrays are 0-indexed but [ranges are 1-indexed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()).

Comment: I've updated the code and changed to the built-in checkboxes like you recommended however I'm still getting duplicate PDFs.  I played around with the code a bit trying different combinations of operators and true/false values and I will either get the checkboxes marked and dupe PDFs or checkboxes marked and no PDFs.

Comment: @FeliciaM If you're using the  built-in checkboxes, then the code above will not work because `✔ != true`. Did you already take that into account? If so, could you please revise your question with the updated info?

Comment: Yes, I switched to True/False
`const isPrinted = 13;
  //const check = "False";
  
  let Print = [];
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    if (row[isPrinted] != "True") {
      createPDF(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[9],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[11],row[0]+" Inv "+row[6]+" - "+row[9],docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder);
    }
    Print.push(["True"]);
    });
  
  RemittanceInfo.getRange(2,isPrinted,RemittanceInfo.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(Print);`

Comment: @FeliciaM `"False"` and `"True"` are strings, not booleans. Change your condition to `if (row[isPrinted]) {...}`. (Also, reading that code is really hard when unformatted, which is why I requested that you update it in the question.)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your request.  I've updated my question.

Comment: @FeliciaM I revised my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: I updated the code but I'm still running in the same issue of the pdf either generating vs not generating regardless of the checkbox being ticked.  I tried adding if statements but still run into the same issue.  I'll update my question with the code I've been trying. I've also been have trouble with the print.push so I just made it a comment till I can figure this out.

Comment: @FeliciaM Sorry I wrote the wrong `if` condition when updating yesterday. Also added a final bullet highlighting yet another error of mine.

Comment: Now I'm getting an "Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 2" everytime I try to run the code.  The error is referring to `RemittanceInfo.getRange(2,13,RemittanceInfo.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(Print);`

Comment: @FeliciaM compare that line to what I have in my answer and look at the final bullet

Comment: Yes, I tried your answer originally but get the same error.  Out of curiosity is the `RemittanceInfo.getRange()` a range or array?  I thought that `[ ]` indicated an array?

Comment: I realized I put a `return` in the if statement to see it what would happen.  After removing it, the code ran but I'm still getting duplicates.

Comment: @FeliciaM I think you must have introduced another change somewhere. The code in my response works and you can verify it by running a `console.log(row[checkedColumnIndex])` instead of `createPDF()`. Feel free to update your original post with the new code if you need me to take another look.